# Different Panels' MouseEnter and MouseLeave conflict on Event Order

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, mouseevent, mouseover

Here, I have two side-by-side panel the `first_pnl` and `second_pnl`, the second panel is not visible by default. Initial thoughts of what I need:

- If my cursor is over the the first one (`MouseEnter`)

  - It's `BackColor` would change to Black
  - Second panel would be visible
- If my cursor leaves first one (`MouseLeave`)

  - It's `BackColor` would change back to Gray
  - Second panel would not be visible

Which is simple as:

```
Private Sub PanelMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles first_pnl.MouseEnter
        first_pnl.BackColor = Color.Black
        second_pnl.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub PanelMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles first_pnl.MouseLeave
        first_pnl.BackColor = Color.Gray
        second_pnl.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

But what I want to happen is:

- When the cursor moves to the second panel (which by now is visible)

  - `second_pnl` would remain visible unless the cursor leave its area.
  - It sustains `first_pnl` property as if it where on a `MouseEnter` event

And here's the scenario to be clear:
[image: Scenarios]

And here's my logic of making that possible: (Giving their same events with same code)

```
Private Sub PanelMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles first_pnl.MouseEnter, second_pnl.MouseEnter
        first_pnl.BackColor = Color.Black
        second_pnl.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub PanelMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles first_pnl.MouseLeave, second_pnl.MouseLeave
        first_pnl.BackColor = Color.Gray
        second_pnl.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Looks reasonable, but I think the system consider first the `MouseLeave` of `first_pnl` before it even consider the `MouseEnter` of `second_pnl`.
Any way to do it?

Comment: I think your statements contradict a bit. And why do you need the second panel's events when there is no work with the second panel as your statements at the top only tell what should happen to the first panel so as to do the following things. No where you have mentioned above that second panel should have mouse events, then in your second code why have you inserted events for handling mouse enter and leave at the second panel?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood, but I've mentioned "When the cursor moves to the second panel" yes, it have mouse events.

Comment: Alright. Sorry, I only didn't check clearly.

Comment: You could handle just `MouseEnter` events and use the `MouseEnter` event of the parent container to do what you're current doing on the `MouseLeave` events.

Comment: The mouse events will always occur in the order `enter` > `leave`. So before the second panel raises the `MouseEnter` event, the first panel will raise the `MouseLeave` event and hide the second panel. *Summary:* The second panel will never raise the `MouseEnter` event.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Can't understand what you're pointing, use parent's `MouseEnter` as substitute for `MouseLeave` of child?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Yes sir, I know it does, It's what I'm asking for help...

Comment: When the mouse pointer leaves `first_pnl`, it either enters `second_pnl` or it enters the common parent.  You want to do something different depending on which it does.  Logic dictates that you handle the `MouseEnter` events of `second_pnl` and the parent to do that.

Comment: Battling MouseEnter/Leave like this is a common problem, it will get a lot worse when you start putting controls in these panels.  The workaround is to start a Timer in MouseEnter and in the Tick event check the cursor position to verify the mouse is still hovering over one of the panels.

Answer (score 1):

[jmcilhinney's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323105/different-panels-mouseenter-and-mouseleave-conflict-on-event-order#comment41312543_26323105) solves this easily.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
    first_pnl.BackColor = Color.Gray
    second_pnl.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub first_pnl_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles first_pnl.MouseEnter
    first_pnl.BackColor = Color.Black
    second_pnl.Visible = True
End Sub
```